# numpy append with more than two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, concatenation

I know there are similar questions out there but i cant find the informations I'm looking for.
I have a list of numpy arrays which i want to append to each other in order to form a feature matrix.

I'm able to get the desired result like so:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
d = [10,11,12]
new_array = numpy.append(a, b, 1)
new_array = numpy.append(new_array, c, 1)
new_array = numpy.append(new_array, d, 1)
```

But this is obviously not the right way to do that, since it is very unelegantly solved and doesnt work if i dont specify the arrays to append my name.
I want to do something like that:

```
value = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
for subval, index in enumerate(value):
 new_array = numpy.append(subval[index], subval[index+1], 1)
```

i cant just do something like `new_array = numpy.append(value[0], value[1],1)` because the length of `value` can vary.
The question is now, how to do this correctly?

I also found something like the `concat` method but my math knowledge is not good enough to understand whether it does the same as the first example of code?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `np.concatenate([a,b,c,d])`?

Comment: will that do the same as append?

Comment: `concatenate` is better because it only allocates the needed memory once. Iterative `append` will copy the arrays many time, e.g, your first array gets copied `n-1` times.

Comment: `append` is a way calling `concatenate` with just 2 arrays instead of a whole list of them.  Read its source code.  It's a poorly named (and used) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `value = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]` simply calling `np.array(value)` will do what you want.

Comment: the items in the values list are arrays already